# Fetching crossed records from the database

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
structure_id | substructure_id | hash_id
1              1                 1
1              1                 2
1              2                 1
2              1                 3
2              1                 1
2              2                 2
```

And I want to fetch an intersection for each structure id how many hashes intersect with other structure ids, **with the same hashes in different substructures being distinct**. What I mean is the following output:

```
structure_id | structure_intersected_id | count
1              1                          2
1              2                          2
2              2                          3
2              1                          2
```

Is this possible to achieve with MySQL? So far I have the following query:

```
select t1.structure_id, t2.structure_id, count(*)
from table t1 
inner join table  t2 on t1.hash_id = t2.hash_id
group by t1.structure_id, t2.structure_id;
```

But it doesn't remove duplicated substructure hashes, and is not correct for 1-1, 2-2, 3-3, etc. structure_id pairs.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your counts in the sample output do not appear to match up with the input table.

Comment: They do. Look, for `1-1` there are 2 unique hashes. For `1-2` there are Two unique hashes that are the same in both. For `2-1` the same. And for `2-2` there are 3 unique hashes in structure id 2.

Comment: For `1-2` I see only one unique `hash_id`, namely the value `1`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yup. `1` structure ID contains unique hashes `1` and `2`. `2` structure id contains unique hashes `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: So 2 of them are the same - `1` and `2`. Thus count is 2, not 1.

Comment: If we'd for example add `2` `1` `2` row to the table from the top, the result would still be `2`.

Comment: Can you add the second table also?

Comment: What second table? There's self join, no other tables.